# apache basic authenticaion

Tags: apache-httpd, authentication

I have enabled basic authentication for one of the directories on website. 
The code has been added in the `httpd.conf` file. 
The user and passwords have been added in the `/etc/passwd` file. The same path has been entered in the `httpd.conf`.
Checked that all the modules i.e. basic, auth, rewrite etc are being loaded in apache.

Problem - once I try and access the folder on the website (internet) the authentication popup comes up, however when I fill in the username and password it does not proceed further and keeps showing the popup again and again, without access to the directory.

code of `httpd.conf`

```
<Directory "/srv/www/htdocs/.....">
AllowOverride AuthConfig
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Restricted Files"
# (Following line optional)
AuthBasicProvider file
AuthUserFile "/etc/passwd"
# AuthGroupFile "/etc/group"
Require valid-user
</Directory>
```

Comment: why did you set the AuthUserFile as "/etc/passwd" ? this file is already used for other purposes : containing essential informations about system's accounts

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you don't want to use `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/group` in the `AuthUserFile` and `AuthGroupFile` directives.

I believe you need to create separate files (with the `AuthUserFile` file created and maintained using the `htpasswd` command).

If you want to have Apache authenticate using your normal system accounts, then you need to look at an authentication module that uses something like PAM (I found [this](http://www.adelton.com/apache/mod_authnz_pam/) but I have no idea if it is any good - I've never used it).

Comment: All in all it is not a good idea to add normal Unix user accounts expressly for web pages authentication.

Answer (score 0):

As Murray suggested you could create an other file ( that is not `/etc/passwd` ), and then as [described here](http://www.webreference.com/programming/apache_authentication/index.html), you can proceed as follow in order to create Basic Authentication users :

```
htpasswd -c /path/to/your/file username
```

this will prompt you to enter a password that will be encrypt and saved into the file defined above. **Note** that if you want to create an other user (more than one) you need to remember to omit the `-c` parameter :

```
htpasswd /path/to/your/file username
```

Otherwise your file will be re-created, and you will overwrite the previous added user(s)

```
htpasswd --help
```

> -c  Create a new file.

additionally, consider that you can decide what encryption algorithm to use for password encryption:

> -m  Force MD5 encryption of the password.
>
> -d  Force CRYPT encryption of the password (default).
>
> -p  Do not encrypt the password (plaintext).
>
> -s  Force SHA encryption of the password.

Comment: thanx plz, I am using apache ver 2.2.12 and the command htpasswd does not work. I have been using useradd and passwd commands is that ok?

Comment: using suse enterprise server 11 sp3

Comment: thanx a ton found it it is usr/bin as htpasswd2

Comment: good, I'm glad of that, remember to accept an answer if there is one that resolved you issue. And in case vote